# How do you make the two columns of double array within a cell into a struct (in matlab)

Tags: matlab, struct, cell

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCMja.jpg)I currently have a 102 x 2 cell, that contains 102 columns and 2 rows of 80 x 1 doubles. I would like to make these two columns into a 1x1 struct. At the end of the day, I would like to have a 102 x 1 cell with 102 1 x 1 structs which each contain two 80 x 1 doubles (and is there a way to label these doubles)?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Could you give an example of data?

Comment: Hi @geoinformatic, I can't add images to my post yet, so here is a link (https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCMja.jpg). The image above is the code I currently have. The box on the lower left is the current data format that I have, and the box on the lower right is the desired outcome (but instead of 4 structs, I would like 102 structs). I hope this is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `deal` to convert the cell content into struct and `arrayfun` to split this large struct into cells:

```
% random data 
X = rand(102,80,2);
% convert each row into a cell
Y = squeeze(num2cell(X,2));
Y = cellfun(@transpose,Y,'UniformOutput',0);
% generate struct
s = struct([]);
s(size(Y,1),1).data1 = [];
s(size(Y,1),1).data2 = [];
% assign struct values
[s(:).data1] = deal(Y{:,1});
[s(:).data2] = deal(Y{:,2});
% convert 102x1 struct into cell
C = arrayfun(@(i) s(i),1:numel(s),'UniformOutput',0).';
```

Comment: Yusss! Thank you. 

In terms of formatting, the script works like a gem. 

The only question is that, I don't know which data this script is extracting. My original cell had multiple fields (data.choice,data.outcome,data.location etc.), but I would only like to make two fields within each struct (data.choice and data.outcome). How can I specify this in your script?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm a little confused here. you're saying your original **cell** had **fields**. is the original variable a cell or a struct?

Comment: Sorry! Didn't mean to confuse you. I think I figured it out. Thanks for your help!